# Prove that if $\gcd(a, n)=1$, then $n\mid a^k-1$ for some $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show that if $a$ and $n$ are natural numbers with the condition that $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then there exists a natural number $k$ such that $n \mid a^{k}-1$

What I tried doing is set it up in mod form such that $a^{k}\equiv1 \pmod n$ and then by Euler's theorem we have $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1 \pmod n$ so I tried to say that $k$ is a subset of $\phi (n)$

What do you think?

Comment: You should just say that we can take $k=\varphi(n)$. (And any multiple of $\varphi(n)$ will do. Often a $k$ substantially less than $\varphi(n)$ will do. If you do not yet have Euler's Theorem, you will need to use a different proof, say by considering $a,a^2,a^3,\dots$.

Comment: I am allowed to use Euler's theorem, I just don't know how I should state it. Since a^phiN and a^k are logically equivalent mod n doesn't that mean that k is a factor of phiN hence is a natural number?

Comment: Since $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, we have that $n$ divides $a^{\varphi(n)}-1$. The end.

Comment: LOL. Thanks, you're really smart

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to show is that there *exists*  *some* $k$ such that $n\,|\, a^k-1$,
then consider the *residues* of $a, a^2, \cdots, a^{n+1}$ modulo $n$.
These $n+1$ residues cannot all be different since the residues can take on
only the $n$ values $0,1,\ldots, n-1$.  So, there exist distinct
integers $i, j \in \{1,2, \ldots , n+1\}$ such that $a^i \equiv a^j \bmod n$. 
Assuming without loss of generality that $i > j$, we have that
$n$ is a divisor of $a^i - a^j = a^j(a^{i-j} - 1)$, and since $n$ has no
factors in common with $a$ and hence no factors in common with $a^j$, 
it must be that $n$ is a divisor of $a^{i-j}-1$.
Set $k = i-j$ and we are done, and all without any knowledge of Euler's theorem.